# How to send Date with UTC+3 applied on TimePicker object of antd?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd, timepicker

I defined Form.Item and TimePicker inside of it. I use this form to send POST, but when I post 16:35 it sent 13:35. It doesn't count the UTC offset. CreationTime works fine, because it uses Date.now() method. How can I post the date with UTC+3 applied.

```
<Modal visible={visible} cancelText={L('Cancel')} okText={L('OK')} onCancel={onCancel} onOk={onCreate} title={'Leave'} destroyOnClose={true}>
  <Form ref={this.props.formRef}>
    <Tabs defaultActiveKey='userInfo' size='small' tabBarGutter={64}>
      <TabPane tab={L('Leave Day')} key='leaveDay'>
        <Form.Item label={L('Leave Date')} {...formItemLayout} name='leaveDate' rules={rules.leaveDate as []}>
          <DatePicker />
        </Form.Item>
      </TabPane>
      <TabPane tab={L('Leave Time Range')} key='leaveTimeRange'>
        <Form.Item label={L('Start Time')} {...formItemLayout} name='leaveStartTime' rules={rules.leaveStartTime as []}>
          <TimePicker />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item label={L('End Time')} {...formItemLayout} name='leaveEndTime' rules={rules.leaveEndTime as []}>
          <TimePicker />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item name='leaveState' initialValue={0} />
        <Form.Item name='creationTime' initialValue={(new Date(Date.now())).toLocaleString()} />
      </TabPane>
    </Tabs>
  </Form>
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

TimePicker and DatePicker use momentjs. Change Dto's data types from Date to Moment and change the utc attribute false to true.

```
@action
async create(createLeaveInput: CreateOrUpdateLeaveInput) {
  createLeaveInput.leaveDate.utc(true);
  createLeaveInput.leaveStartTime.utc(true);
  createLeaveInput.leaveEndTime.utc(true);
  const result = await leaveService.create(createLeaveInput);
  this.leaves.items.push(result);
}
```